# How to alter connection string only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, powershell, azure-analysis-services

Apparently the databases/cubes in an analysis server contain "script connection as > alter" option like so:

[image: script_connection_as]

I want to use a powershell script like this:

```
    $hashtable = @{}
Import-Csv "CSV_file" | ForEach-Object {
    $hashtable += @{$($_.Server) = ($_.Cube -split '\s*,\s*') }
}

Import-Module SqlServer

foreach($server in $hashtable.Keys){ 

   $Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
   $Analysis_Server.connect("$server") 

   foreach($CUBE in $hashtable[$server]) {

      ####### Setting connection property for $Cube #######
"  
    <Alter ObjectExpansion="ExpandFull" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Object>
        <DatabaseID>$CUBE</DatabaseID>
    </Object>
    <ObjectDefinition>
        <DataSource xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500" xsi:type="RelationalDataSource">
            <ConnectionString>Connection Timeout=60;User Id=someID;Password=pass;Data Source=td.domain.com;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8</ConnectionString>
        </DataSource>
    </ObjectDefinition>
    </Alter>
    "

    }
}
```

that takes input a csv file

> Server,Cube
>
> server1.domain.com,Database1

and loops through the databases/cubes in the server to alter their DataSource `<ConnectionString>`

However i am sure that there is something missing in that script, but the thing is if i run that XML in SSMS, it complain about the `<Name>` element for `<DataSource>` is required. i understand that the full XML is needed, but it wont work from a script perspective that i am trying to accomplish because i cant have the same DataSource for other databases i have in the server. they are all possibly different, so the ID, Name, etc...have to be removed from the XML query in powershell script.

i receive this error

> The object definition supplied for the ALTER statement is of a different type that the object reference to be altered.

---

***Note***: The reason i am not using analysis server properties instead is because the analysis properties method i was trying here [ConnectionString property not printing connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037741/connectionstring-property-not-printing-connection-string)

did not work, and has been escalated to Microsoft as broken property,

Comment: I would say that you need to find a way to retrieve the XML first. Then you can build a valid alter XML and send that back to the server.

Comment: I'm on mobile, so sorry for not being able to validate this. But look at this and see if you can get all the details about a data source: https://mobile.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/analysis-services-powershell-provider-sqlas-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: @Mötz yes, that's what I need help with here, finding a way to ultimately alter the XML file, whether by retrieving it or annotating it like I have in the script. As for your suggested thread, I have tried invokeASCmd, like so: $cs = "ConnectionTimeout=60;UserId=someID;Password=pass;DataSource=td.domain.com;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8"

Import-Csv $CSV_file | ForEach-Object{ Invoke-ASCmd -Server $_.Server -Database $_.Cube -ConnectionString $cs ....but I got error: Invoke-ASCmd : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Comment: You have me a bit confuses with the details. I have placed answer on your other question. Lets take the discussion there.

Comment: @Mötz I was saying that I tried this: Invoke-ASCmd -Server $_.Server -Database $_.Cube -ConnectionString "ConnectionTimeout=60;UserId=someID;Password=pass;DataSource=td.domain.com;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8" ..... but I got error: Invoke-ASCmd : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We learned together that SQL Server 2016 or higher works with at compatibility level of 1200 or higher. Whenever you work on level 1200 or higher you are not able to use the classic AMO objects to work the the different properties.

Microsoft actually states this very clearly: [Programming with Analysis Management Objects (AMO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/amo/developing-with-analysis-management-objects-amo)

*If you are programming for tabular models at 1200 or higher compatibility level, use the **Tabular Object Model (TOM)**. TOM is an extension of the Analysis Services Management Object (AMO) client library.*

Learning about TOM is just like learning about AMO back in the days. You have to start somewhere like this: [Tabular Object Model (TOM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tom/introduction-to-the-tabular-object-model-tom-in-analysis-services-amo)

We found that this works

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$newConnectionString = "Connection Timeout=60;User Id=SOME_NEW_ID;Data Source=10.10.19.10;Persist Security Info=True;Session Character Set=UTF8"

$svr = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
$svr.Connect("server1.domain.com")

$svr.databases[1].model.datasources[0].ConnectionString = $newConnectionString
$svr.Databases[1].Update([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull)
```

Answer (score 1):

So - based on the findings from @thom schumacher from your other question ([located here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53070238/2678467))

```
$Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$Analysis_Server.connect("AX2012R2A")

#Getting current state
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Analysis_Server.Databases | ForEach-Object {$_.datasources | ForEach-Object {$_.ConnectionSt
ring}}
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_4
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_2
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_1
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_6
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_3
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_5

#Setting the new connection string in variable
$connectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_40"

#Assigning the variable to one of the databases
$Analysis_Server.Databases[0].datasources[0].ConnectionString = $connectionString

#Remember to update the new configuration back to the database
$Analysis_Server.Databases[0].datasources[0].Update()

#Getting the new configuration
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $Analysis_Server.Databases | ForEach-Object {$_.datasources | ForEach-Object {$_.ConnectionSt
ring}}
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_40
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_2
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_1
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_6
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_3
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=AX2012R2A;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName_5
```

Please pay attention to the first entry in each list. It went from **DatabaseName_4** to **DatabaseName_40**

That is how you only change the details of the connection string, using PowerShell and SMO.

Comment: it works for compatibility level 1103 databases! finally, but it doesnt work for databases with level 1400. i get this error: The property 'ConnectionString' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set. .... what is the property then for such level? is it different for the 2017 SQL server?

Comment: i cant since i dont have databases of that level. even i had 1200 level databases, i still need it to work for level 1400 (SQL server 2017) however, there is something important to note: apparently the "SQL Server 2012 SP1 or later (1103)" databases, when i try altering the connection as script in SSMS, it shows up as an XML (XMLA) file. however, for the databases with "SQL Server 2017 (1400)", it is not alter, but instead its "replace to" and it generates a JSON file!

Comment: I believe you need to carefully read this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/amo/developing-with-analysis-management-objects-amo

Comment: uh ha! If you are programming for tabular models at 1200 or higher compatibility level, use the Tabular Object Model (TOM).

Comment: And here someone is showing how to do it in powershell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202008/ssas-tabular-switch-among-the-datasource-connections

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183434/discussion-between-motz-and-cataster).

Comment: $svr.databases.model.datasources.ConnectionString

Comment: now if i try updating:.....
$svr.databases[1].model.datasources[0].ConnectionString = $newConnectionString ...............
$svr.Databases[1].model.datasources[0].Update()...........
i get this.............
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource] does not contain a method 
named 'Update'........and if i do this: $svr.Databases[1].model.datasources[0].Update(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateO‌​ptions.ExpandFull)
Unexpected token 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions.ExpandFull' in expression or statement.

Comment: $svr.Databases[1].model.Update()

Comment: The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Update": "Encountered an invalid type for a default value." + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember

Comment: even trying SaveChanges() method i got same error....i dont understand why because https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tom/add-a-data-source-to-tabular-model-analysis-services-amo-tom ....says....To commit changes to the server, call either Model.SaveChanges() or Database.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull).